# jQuery disable checkbox on class

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox

I have the following code that sits within `$( document ).ready(function()`:

```
$('.Spec').prop('disabled', !$('.Spec').is(':checked'));
```

What I am trying to do is when the page has loaded, disable any checkbox with the class `Spec` that are not checked.

Any reason why the above doesn't work?

Comment: @DSG I don't think it does...  if you add a couple more checkboxes to your fiddle, it fails..    http://jsfiddle.net/FMKAn/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To begin with, you're doing a very poorly thought-out selector mechanism for your boolean condition; how is it going to know WHICH particular checkbox within the Spec class is the one you need to evaluate?

I might suggest something more along these lines:

```
$('.Spec').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works a treat - many thanks.  I've taken on-board the feedback about the boolean condition, thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

`!$('.Spec').is(':checked')` will return false if any checkbox with that class is presently checked, so all checkboxes would have to be unchecked.

It sounds like you're trying to do this individually on each checkbox, so something like :

```
$('.Spec').prop('disabled', function() {
     return !this.checked;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No idea, however, this should work.

```
$('.spec').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, I tried to implement David as you were quick to reply but this doesn't work.  A couple of differences between yours and Vector Gorogth's reply with the use of `!` and removal of `:` and likely the use of `prop` twice?

Comment: Sorry, was about to leave, so i didn't have time to test. I know the other answer worked, however I edited mine so that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var _checked;
$('.Spec').each(function() {
    _checked = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? false : true;
    $(this).prop('disabled', _checked);
});
```

See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FMKAn/3/)

Comment: Thanks Rahil, I went with Vector's in the end as it was a little more succinct.